# Exponential maps depends on Riemannian metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

This may be a silly question but I am new to Riemannian  Geometry.

If I have two *different* Riemannian Metrics $g_1,g_2$ on a smooth manifold $M$, then do the geodesics on the Riemannian manifolds $(M,g_1)$ and $(M,g_2)$ differ?  That is do the Exponential maps depend on our choice of Riemannian metric?

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301858/could-a-riemannian-metric-be-uniquely-determined-by-its-exponential-map/3614249#3614249

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sure. You change the definition of length, so you change the shortest paths between two given points, so change $\exp$.

(Edit: A nice visualization you get  by looking at the upper half plane in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If this is equipped with the standard Euclidean metric, a geodesic is a straight line. If you use $g_{ij} = \frac{1}{y^2}\delta_{ij}$ you get one standard model of hyperbolic space, and the geodesics are half circles with center on the line $y=0$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model))

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas :)

Comment: The example is also extremely helpful!

Comment: @thomas Do you know something about converse? I mean, if the exponential maps are equal than are the metrics isometric?

Comment: @melomm this is way more tricky. See, e.g., here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132244/can-one-recover-a-metric-from-geodesics